# Which is the best way to install Nginx And apache together in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, laravel, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I have a VPS server and try to install *Apache* and *Nginx* to work together in *Ubuntu 16.04* but with different server Names and domains.

So, I have apache to port 8000 and nginx to port 8080.

Nginx do go to 8080 port because use *NodeJs* and this uses behind the route https://localhost:8080/

Apache uses Laravel 5.5 and PHP.

I have already configure to Apache

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000.default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName www.myanotherdomainname.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`/ect/apache2/ports.conf` with `Listen 8000`

For Nginx in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

And

```
server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name geckode.la www.mydomain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

In **www.mydomain.com**, the script.js run by NodeJs works fine

But in **www.myanotherdomainname.com**, return **404 Not Found** *nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)*

It doesn't even seem to run apache

I need to know the best way to run apache and nginx with Nodejs.

*Apache* status and *Nginx* are running without any problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just doing what you told it to do. Let's run through your config:

`if ($host = www.mydomain.com)` - Nope...

`if ($host = mydomain.com)` - Still nope...

`return 404;` - OK, Ooops, I mean HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Thanks!, but finally i did decide use the  both domains in nginx